# Static lists in Python for arithmetic manipulations

Tags: python, list, math

I've a list similar to

```
a = ['12*b+20*c+30*d']
```

I keep replacing the values `b,c,d` using the the `replace` function in python
by using something like this

```
mapping = [ ('b', `float(3)`), ('c', `float(2)`), ('d', `float(1)`)]
for k, v in mapping:
    a[0] = a[0].replace(k, v)
```

and then perform some arithmetic operation on it.

I would like to have a `static list`, retains the list `a` instead of changing it to

```
a = ['12*3+20*2+30*1']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just format the string?

```
l = '12*%d+20*%d+30*%d'%(b, c, d)
```

Actually, the question is, why do you even put the equation in a string? Are you going to use `eval`?

You can put it in a function instead:

```
def calculate(constants, *args):
    num = 0

    for c, v in zip(constants, *args):
        num +=  c*v
    return num
```

Demo:

```
>>> def calculate(constants, *args):
        num = 0
        for c, v in zip(constants, args):
            num +=  c*v
        return num

>>> calculate([12, 20, 30], b, c, d)
204
```

Which is equal to:

```
>>> 12 * b + 20 * c + 30 * d
204
```

Or even, if the constants will always be the same:

```
def calculate(b, c, d):
    return 12 * b + 20 * c + 30 * d
```

Comment: Do you want me to change the list as well in this format:
a=['12*%d+20*%d+30*%d']

Comment: Yeah, that would be better. You can also try my updated solution, which is much cleaner.

Comment: Also, do you really need to use a list?

Comment: Yes, because I've a lot of these arithmetic operations going on and I don't want to read each one them from a file or put them in a different list, which would increase confusion. and Yes, I was using `eval`. The actually list looks like this. a = ['z = 12*b+20*c+30*d']

Comment: In your format, the constants always have to given as an input in the list, which is not really flexible when you've multiple operations.

Comment: You can just put the constants in the function. I'm doing it on purpose, in case you need the constants to be flexible.

Comment: >>> calculate(*[12, 20, 30]*, b, c, d), The list in italic tickle me. I will search for a method to improve that. It'll be great to have more flexibility.